# Substitute elements of a matrix at specific coordinates in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am struggling to write code to substitute particular values in a matrix.

I have a matrix, C, that contains multiple [r,c,v] values. I now want to use these co-ordinates to substitute values from matrix X with those from matrix Y- but only at the coordinates in matrix c. At the coordinates not in matrix c I would like to retain the values from matrix X.

As a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
o1= [ 123 123 123; 123 255 123; 255 123 123];
o2= [ 4 4 4; 4 4 4; 4 4 4];
d1= [111 111 111; 111 255 111; 111 111 111];
d2= [5 5 5; 5 5 5; 5 5 5];

o_p= o1;
d_p= d1;
```

need to find coordinates in o_p  and d_p where the values equal 255

```
[r,c,v] = find(o_p==255);
a= [r, c, v];

[r,c,v] = find(d_p==255);
b= [r, c, v];

c= [a; b];
```

Then I want to use the coordinates in c to replace the elements at these coordinates in both matrices with o2 and d2 respectively

Comment: How does `Matrix C` map to `Matrix X` and `Matrix Y`?

Comment: o1= [ 123 123 123; 123 255 123; 255 123 123];
o2= [ 4 4 4; 4 4 4; 4 4 4];
d1= [111 111 111; 111 255 111; 111 111 111];
d2= [5 5 5; 5 5 5; 5 5 5];

Comment: sorry 1 minute- hadn't finished

Comment: o1= [ 123 123 123; 123 255 123; 255 123 123];
o2= [ 4 4 4; 4 4 4; 4 4 4];
d1= [111 111 111; 111 255 111; 111 111 111];
d2= [5 5 5; 5 5 5; 5 5 5];
% 2 new matrices
% values initially set at those from longest exposure time (pixel dwell)
o_p= o1;
d_p= d1;
% need to find coordinates in o_p (o1) and d_p (d1) where the values equal 255
[r,c,v] = find(o_p==255);
a= [r, c, v];

[r,c,v] = find(d_p==255);
b= [r, c, v];

c= [a; b];

Comment: Why not edit your question altogether? It's easier for you and us.

Comment: then take coordinates from c and change the values of the elements at these coordinates to those from o1 and d1 to those from o2 and d2

Comment: It's confusing to look at codes here in comments. Please use the `Edit` option under the `Question` posted and put the codes and your comments there in question.

Comment: sorry I didn't realise that I was able to edit the questions- as you can tell I'm very new to this! Thanks for your patience- please see above

Comment: When you said `need to find coordinates in o_p and d_p where the values equal 255`. Do you mean `255` to be present in both [`o_p` **and** `d_p`] OR [`o_p` **or** `d_p`]?

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't entirely clear, but I'm going to make some assumptions and hopefully the solution is close to what you're looking for.

```
% Example

x = rand(12,12);
y = ones(12,12);
% Assume c = [x,y]
c = [1 1; 2 2; 3 3; 4 4];  % Pick a few arbitrary points on the diagonal
x(sub2ind(size(x),c(:,1),c(:,2))) = y(sub2ind(size(x),c(:,1),c(:,2)))
```

In order to do this in one line you can take advantage of how MATLAB stores values in memory. Because MATLAB technically stores matrix in a single column, you can access any value in the matrix with a 1D index instead of nD coordinates. `sub2ind` allows you to obtain these indices based on the input coordinates and size of the matrix, which you can then use to swap values between matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 255 to be present in both [o_p **and** d_p] or [o_p **or** d_p]?

If **and** try this -

```
ind1 = find((o_p==255) & (d_p==255))
```

If **or** try this -

```
ind1 = find((o_p==255) | (d_p==255))
```

and then do -

```
o2(ind1)=d2(ind1)
```

Hope this is what you are after!